# Best way to pass complex data structures (e.g., list of dictionaries) between Python, Node, and client

Tags: python, node.js, json, sockets, data-structures

My website needs to pass data between a client, a Node server, and a Python child process. The website needs to pass data both ways (client>Node>Python AND Python>Node>client).

I have trouble with JSON.stringify and JSON.parse because the data structures are complex. For example, an array of 3 products:

```
Product 1 = {country: ['US', 'FRANCE'], type: car, price: ['USD 15000', 'EUR 10000']}

Product 2 = {country: ['US', 'ITALY'], type: accessory, price: ['USD 150', 'EUR 100']}

Product 3 = {country: ['GERMANY', 'ITALY'], type: car, price: ['USD 25000', 'EUR 15000']}

is 'damaged' at some point and turns into this:

Product 1 = {country: '[US, FRANCE]', type: 'car', price: '[USD 15000, EUR 10000]'}

Product 2 = {country: '[US, ITALY]', type: 'accessory', price: '[USD 150, EUR 100]'}

Product 3 = {country: '[GERMANY, ITALY]', type: 'car', price: '[USD 25000, EUR 15000]'}
```

This means, for example, that Product 1 is only available in the nonsense country '[US, FRANCE]' and has the nonsense price of '[USD 15000, EUR 10000]'

Is there a better way to do this, like using a temporary CSV file, an external library, etc.? I need something that guarantees data quality in the Python>Node> client and the client>Node>Python directions.

I would like to avoid encoding (for example, 'US' = 1, 'FRANCE' = 2, etc.) because this will not work when the data structures become more complex (FYI - that the website will be updated in the future to allow for more complexity).

The examples are hypothetical and simplified. The actual data structures are more complicated.

Thanks a lot!!
Felipe

Comment: Can you elaborate the damaging part more? How and where does it happen?

Comment: Just a note, this damaging does not happen in python using `json.dumps` and `json.loads` so the problem is elsewhere. For OP, I would absolutely use json for this, we just need to identify what is mangling your data and fix that.

Comment: "is 'damaged' at some point and turns into this:" That is not an adequate problem specification. Please provide a [mcve]. JSON is typical solution to your problem.

Comment: Just what others already stated: the proper solution is to fix the 'damaging' issue, not to switch to a format that's both inappropriate AND much more tricky to properly generate and parse.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I found that 
the damage happens not in the Python-Node-client connection, but when Python writes the data in a permanent sqlite database. This turns {country: ['US', 'FRANCE']} into {country: "['US', 'FRANCE']"}
This happens because I can't store arrays in sqlite fields, so I need to convert them to strings.
I would use a txt file instead of sqlite to avoid the 'data corruption', but I need to query the DB by country and a txt file is not ideal for this. Is there an option that allows me to store arrays without corrupting them AND use them for queries?
Thanks!!

Comment: @Felipe you could use something like postgres instead of sqlite. postgres supports JSON types natively. If you can use `sqlite` in python, then you can use `psycopg2` in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you!! this works great!!!